# Alexandroff works in english

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, reference-request

Are Alexandroff's "Matematičeskiı̆ Sbornik (Receul Mathématique), 2 (44), N.
3:502–519, 1937." and "Topologie, Erster Band: Grundbegriffe der  engentheoretischen Topologie · Topologie der Komplexe · Topologische Invarianzstze und anschließende Begriffsbildungen · Verschlingungen
im m–dimensionalen euklidischen Raum · stetige Abbildungen von Polyedern, (Die Grundlehrender mathematischen Wissenschaften in Einzeldarstellungen, Band XLV), Verlag von Julius Springer, Berlin, 1935." available in English? How can I find them?

Comment: Just learn German. I did and enough Russian to read some topology papers.

Comment: The German was at regular school of course (as any Dutchman has to). It's way better than my Russian.

Comment: Would this also help? "Alexandroff. Elementary concepts in Topology (1932)".